# CakePHP: download generated QR Code

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, qr-code

I'm starting a CakePHP Helper based on [phpqrcode](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode). My problem is that i can't get the generated png or svg file and force the browser to download it.

i want to when a person submit his text via Ajax, i generate a QR Code for him and force the browser to download it without saving the file on the server.

Here is a short example of the Helper:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'QRGenerator.phpqrcode'.DS.'qrlib');

class QRHelper extends AppHelper{

    function text($content= '') {

        QRcode::png($content);

    }   
}
```

In my view file:

```
<?php $this->QR->text('example text'); ?>
```

And my layout:

```
<?php  echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try with return or echo `QRcode::png($content);` in `text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
    $this->response->type('Content-Type: image/png');
    $this->response->download('qrcode.png');
```

Comment: there is no .png physical file, the helper generate .png files directly to the browser

Comment: Yes I know.  The code I posted just sets the headers of the response so that the file is downloaded, not displayed in the browser.

Comment: Thanks it works fr png files but for svg or eps files it generates files with 0 bytes !!
$this->response->type('eps');
$this->response->download('qrcode.eps');
Is this true ?

Comment: It works :) for png files i shouldn't add an echo to QRcode::png($content); but for svg and eps i should add it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with return or echo QRcode::png($content); in text()

```
  function text($content= '') {

       return QRcode::png($content);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [QR Code Helper](https://github.com/muxe/cakePHP-QR-Code-Helper):

- Copy the "QrCodeHelper.php" to your "app/View/Helper" folder.
- In the Controller add 'QrCode' to your helpers array.
- In the view do for example:

  ```
  <? echo $this->QrCode->text('Hello World'); ?>
  ```