# CakePHP 2.x QR Code generation and download

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Objective:**

Generate QR code images for a set of strings and download them.

**What I've tried so far:**

I've used QrCodeHelper from the following link: [QR Code Helper](https://github.com/muxe/cakePHP-QR-Code-Helper)

So far, I'm just developing a simple test QR code from a random string.

In the view view.ctp, I've written:

```
  echo $this->QrCode->text("ABCD"); // This generates a QR code image
```

And in the controller, I've written:

```
  public function view() {
      $this->response->type('Content-Type: image/png');
      $this->response->download('qrcode.png');
  }
```

When the page is loaded, an image qrcode.png is being downloaded, but it's showing an error: "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer"

There's no problem with the photo viewer.

I know a similar question had been asked earlier: [CakePHP: download generated QR Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430837/cakephp-download-generated-qr-code)

But it didn't solve my problem.

Any help would be highly aprpeciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QrCode Helper you've used probably isn't really a good fit for what you need. Helpers are meant to help with views - which it's doing correctly but in this instance you want/need to use the helper within the controller, which doesn't really work (and, what makes things more complex is this particular Helper returns the QRCode within an image tag).

You could achieve this relatively easily though using [PHP QR Code](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode)

Download PHPQRCode and put the files in `/vendors/phpqrcode/` in your Cake installation and include the following in your controller (note: untested)

```
public function view($text = 'ABCD') {

    // Don't render a view file
    $this->autoRender = false; 

    // Tell the borwser to download the file (slug it, too)
    $this->response->download(Inflector::slug($text) . '.png');

    // Import the vendor lib
    App::import("Vendor", "phpqrcode/qrlib");

    // Bombs away
    QRcode::png($text);

}
```

More information on PHP QR Code: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

you can download your Qr code Librairie in you App/lib

the name of class used must be the same name of file

And include your file like that :

?>
not you can use your your QRcode simply .